# Should we change the Password in the Application pool in server if the Active Directory ID password is reset?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, windows-server-2016, activedirectorymembership

We are resetting the password of Active directory service account used in server for

1. Identity in Application Pool
2. Certificate  Access Permission
3. Folder share access permissions
4. Windows Scheduler job permission
5. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Services > EventLog (Permissions)

Should we modify the all the places after password reset?

Answer (score 0):

***No need to reset password for application pool***.You can directly entered into application pool but for accessing the `sites` presents in **`application pool`** using identity.You will need new password that you have reset`(Indirectly we can say for application pool it auto update the password there is no need of separately change password of application pool)`.

> Windows Domain accounts are used as identities to run IIS App Pools.
> Whenever the password of a domain account is changed in the domain
> controller, the new password has to be updated individually in all
> associated App Pools for web applications to run without any
> hindrance. With each domain account running numerous App Pools,
> changing all the passwords manally becomes tedious.

***Same for*** ***Certificate Access Permission***, ***Folder share access permissions***, ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Services > EventLog (Permissions)*** ***we don't require change passoword***.

It is different for **`Windows Scheduler job permission`** we need to change password because in backend Window Scheduler Job is working with old password but all the schedule job will be failed.You need to update the password manually here.

***For more information you can refer this [Document](https://www.manageengine.com/products/passwordmanagerpro/help/iis_apppool_account_reset.html)***